# what is difference between this 2 typeScript code?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.7

what is difference between this 2 typeScript code?(I use typeScript 1.7.5)

```
interface SquareConfig {
  color?: string;
  width?: number;
}

function createSquare(config: SquareConfig): {color: string; area: number} {
  var newSquare = {color: "white", area: 100};
  if (config.color) {
    newSquare.color = config.color;
  }
  if (config.width) {
    newSquare.area = config.width * config.width;
  }
  return newSquare;
}

var obj = {color1: "black"};
var mySquare = createSquare(obj);
```

when is compile not error but below code production error.

```
interface SquareConfig {
  color?: string;
  width?: number;
}

function createSquare(config: SquareConfig): {color: string; area: number} {
  var newSquare = {color: "white", area: 100};
  if (config.color) {
    newSquare.color = config.color;
  }
  if (config.width) {
    newSquare.area = config.width * config.width;
  }
  return newSquare;
}

var mySquare = createSquare({color1: "black"});
```

error:

> test.ts(18,30): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ color1: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SquareConfig'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'color1' does not exist in type 'SquareConfig'.

Comment: rename `color1` to `color`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your examples have the same (perceived) error, which is that you have specified a property that isn't known to `SquareConfig`, which often means you have mis-typed a property name.

In your case you have specified `color1` where you probably intended to use `color`.

This code would have compiled using older versions of TypeScript before this additional feature of checking for unspecified properties was added.

Fixes...

Option One, specify the correct property:

```
var mySquare = createSquare({color: "black"});
```

Option Two, you are deliberately intending to include some other property, use a type assertion to tell the compiler you know better than it does (as long as you are sure you do in fact know better than it does!):

```
var mySquare = createSquare(<SquareConfig>{color1: "black"});
```

## Update based on comment

The compiler is more strict the less "degrees of separation" you have... for example:

```
// Error
var obj: SquareConfig = {color1: "black"};

// OK
var obj = {color1: "black"};
var obj2: SquareConfig = obj;
```

Let's look at the first example, we are saying "I intend to create a `SquareConfig`". The compiler says, "well, there are no *required* items as everything is optional, but you are creating the object with a property I don't recognise - so I'll warn you".

The second example is slightly different. We are saying "I intend to use an object that I have as a `SquareConfig`". The compiler says, "is the object you intend to use missing any required properties... and does each property have the correct type to be a structural match for a `SquareConfig` - yes."

If the second scenario warned you about properties that don't exist on the target structure, you'd wouldn't be able to take advantage of the uber-polymorphism that a structural type system offers.

Comment: The OP's code is from the TypeScript handbook, which does not explain why there is a parameter list with types after the config parameter declaration:

(config: SquareConfig): {color: string; area: number}

The ": {color: string; area: number}" can be removed and it still compiles, so why did they include it?